# dSYM download when Bitcode is disabled

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, traceback, dsym, rollbar

To use the Rollbar service, Bitcode needs to be disabled for traceback symbolization. I also have to upload the dSYM file to Rollbar. But where do I get the dSYM file when Bitcode is disabled? Normally I can download the file from App Store Connect but it seems that I only can download them from the App Store Connect when Bitcode is enabled - or am I wrong?. I do not see any download links if Bitcode is disabled.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like dSYM files are only accessible through App Store Connect when Bitcode is enabled. If you have Bitcode enabled in your application’s project settings, the dSYM files available on your machine will not contain the information needed to symbolicate crash reports. Instead, dSYM files are generated by the App Store when your app is recompiled after upload.

That's why, we need to use the local dSYM files. Locate the files from the Xcode Organizer. Go to *Window* > *Organiser* > Select the app > Select the build > Right click on it > Select "Show in Finder" > Right click on the file > Choose "Show Package Contents" > Finally, go to the `dSYMs` folder.

Comment: is there any other way to do this? I cannot enable bitcode because every time I do I get an error "Linker command failed with exit code 0". And when I try to use the method you mentioned above, when I click the dsym folder to compress it, it hands on "compressing 0 items..."

Comment: @Kevin You saved me. Thank you!